# How to append text to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have written this code to take 3 parameters and assign to variable.now i want to append the text i am getting throughparameter to div fontdiv 
how to do this?

here is what i have tried..

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) {
    var elem = '<div id="fontdiv" style="position: absolute;visibility: visible;height: auto;"></div>';
    $('body').append($(elem));
    var fontdiv = document.getElementById('fontdiv');
    fontdiv.style.fontSize = fontsize;
    fontdiv.style.fontFamily = fontname;
    $("#fontdiv").html($('text').val());
    return fontdiv.clientWidth;
};
```

Comment: what is `$('text').val()` ?

Comment: i am appending value of text parameter to font div....Is it correct?

Comment: No..just use `$("#fontdiv").html(text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of text is set already (and it seems to be), use :

```
$("#fontdiv").append(text);
```

And it should work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this has been answered already in the exact same way. +1 pXL!

Answer (score 3):

If your `text` param already has text

```
$("#fontdiv").append(text);    // append text into fontdiv
```

Comment: Or to append : `$("#fontdiv").html($("#fontdiv").html()+someValidHTML);`

Comment: Or `$("#fontdiv").append(text)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('body').append($(elem));
```

with

```
$('body').append(elem);
```

Comment: And what is $('text').val();

Comment: Why are you suggesting this ? [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) accepts a jQuery element as parameter. This isn't an answer.

Comment: bec he got the html from elem ,and he need to append the html to the body

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) {
    var elem = '<div id="fontdiv" style="position: absolute;visibility: visible;height: auto;"></div>';
    var el = $(elem).append(text);
    $('body').append(el);
    var fontdiv = document.getElementById('fontdiv');
    fontdiv.style.fontSize = fontsize;
    fontdiv.style.fontFamily = fontname;
    $("#fontdiv").html($('text').val());
    return fontdiv.clientWidth;
};
```

Another way could be

```
function getTextWidth(text, fontname, fontsize) {
    var el = $('<div>', {
        id: 'fontdiv'
    }).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        visibility: 'visible',
        height: 'auto',
        fontSize: fontsize,
        fontFamily: fontname
    }).append(text).appendTo('body');
    return el.get(0).clientWidth;
};
```